# How to organize a collection of URLs on an intranet?

Tags: website-design, lists, grouped-list, intranet

As in most big organizations there is a lot information to be found on the intranet but unfortunately most users have difficulty quickly finding what they are looking for.

We do have a full text search but this gives very poor results, so this isn't used much.

We also have a very simple static page (maintained centrally) that contains a number of popular URLs (about a hundred or so). These URLs are grouped by region (Global, US, Europe...) and by content type (IT, HR, policies, training...) This page is the second most popular page on the intranet (after the homepage)! So there is a real need for it and I want this page to be redesigned and have it a more 21st century look and feel.

Any suggestions here?

Some additional info: although it is a high-tech company, the user population is a typical engineering audience which is not (yet) into things like responsive design, word clouds...

Here is an example of how a small part of this url collection looks like. This is the IT part :

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about visual design or content structure and strategy? Also, your audience doesn't have to be 'into' responsive design to appreciate the benefits. Who creates a responsive design or responsive content based on whether their audience is 'ready' for such mystical wonders?

Comment: I have added an example of what we have right now.
A few tabs at the top to select the region and then static lists of url's. Should we use a word cloud, or some other more advanced way of filtering the lists or is this simple static lists the best representation for this purpose ? So I guess it is more about the visual design.

Comment: The simple and easiest improvement would be to alphabetize everything, both the larger "tabs" or categories, and the subcategories underneath.

Comment: I would argue against alphabetisation and instead organise both the sections and links by popularity, starting with the most commonly used at the top.

Comment: This article about ordering gives some alternatives: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/alphabetical-sorting-must-mostly-die/

Answer (score 2):

Providing different routes to content is a common challenge made more complex in global organisations where local, regional and global content all compete for attention. This article discusses [how to surface the content people actually need](http://www.steptwo.com.au/papers/kmc_shopwindo). Your links page is clearly useful to people, so find out what they struggle with and work on improving it. Questionnaires, observation and card sorting will all help.

Your existing categorisations look good. If they work well, people may be used to the way they're organised, in which case don't change them drastically. Instead, experiment with presenting the links in different ways so people can find what they need more quickly. This may mean separating groups of links across different pages and organising them by the most popular. Name and organise the pages and links according the user's understanding, rather than who the business owner is.

Alternatively, you may decide to implement megamenu navigation and do away with the links page(s) altogether. This will allow you to separate and organise the links in whatever way you choose, while making the navigation do the work it was intended to do.

Comment: +1 on a card sort, robust search, and strong governance.  You won't be able to make all users happy, but paving the cow paths and making things as discoverable as possible is key.  A note on governance - make sure you have a clear process as to what constitutes additions to the core menu system, otherwise you get a lot of pet projects and on-offs that can get out of control quickly